# dotnet-dump limited to .net core applications?

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection

I started a memory leak investigation following the post [Finding that C# memory leak](https://timdeschryver.dev/blog/finding-that-csharp-memory-leak#analysing-a-dump-file).
I created the dump with task manager and wanted to analyze it with dotnet-dump. My application is for .net framework (4.6), not for .net core, I'm not sure it is supported by dotnet-dump.
When I launch **dotnet-dump analyze** it doesn't complain, but **dumpheap -stat** and any other command I tried give the following error:

> Format of the executable (.exe) or library (.dll) is invalid.

I loaded the dump into PerfView too, the result is the same, it complains about the format. So, what tools and procedures do I have to analyze heap memory usage of a .net framework applications ?

**UPDATE 1**

DotMemory expains the format error better:

> Unable to import the dump: 64-bit dumps of 32-bit processes are currently not supported. Please use a 32-bit tool to take a dump. For example, %WinDir%\SysWOW64\taskmgr.exe is a 32-bit version of Task Manager.

I'm going to create a new dump

**UPDATE 2**

I launched taskmanager from %WinDir%\SysWOW64, but dump creation fails with no error message. I noticed some warnings in the event log, I will investigate them. I definitely would need a step by step simple tutorial to make some practice.

Comment: If you already have the dotMemory, profile your application with it, it will show you more information then memory dump in most cases.

Comment: Finally I could analyze some dumps. I had no luck with TaskManager in **%WinDir%\SysWOW64**, then I decided to try **dotnet-dump collect** after downloading the x86 version. Now I have some data but I'm not sure about their meaning. I'm going to open a new question. To summarize it is no matter of .net core vs .net framework as I thought initially, but if you have a 32 bit process you need a 32 bit dumping tool.